# Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, auto-increment

I am trying to maintain an address history table:

```
CREATE TABLE address_history (
    person_id int, 
    sequence int,
    timestamp datetime default current_timestamp,
    address text,
    original_address text,
    previous_address text,
    PRIMARY KEY(person_id, sequence),
    FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people.id
);
```

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to autonumber/constrain `sequence` in `address_history` to automatically count up from 1 for each `person_id`.

In other words, the first row with `person_id = 1` would get `sequence = 1`; the second row with `person_id = 1` would get `sequence = 2`. The first row with `person_id = 2`, would get `sequence = 1` again. Etc.
Also, is there a better / built-in way to maintain a history like this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Don't. It has been tried many times and it's a pain.

Use a plain `serial` or `IDENTITY` column:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

```
CREATE TABLE address_history (
  address_history_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, person_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES people(id)
, created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
, previous_address text
);
```

Use the window function `row_number()` to get serial numbers without gaps per `person_id`. You could persist a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) that you can use as drop-in replacement for your table in queries to have those numbers ready:

```
CREATE VIEW address_history_nr AS
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id
                             ORDER BY address_history_id) AS adr_nr
FROM   address_history;
```

See:

- [Gap-less sequence where multiple transactions with multiple tables are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578014/need-gap-less-sequence-where-multiple-transactions-with-multiple-tables-is-invol/22578288#22578288)

Or you might want to `ORDER BY` something else. Maybe `created_at`? Better `created_at, address_history_id` to break possible ties. Related answer:

- [Column with alternate serials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359034/column-with-alternate-serials/12359291#12359291)

Also, the data type you are looking for is `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, not <strike>`datetime`</strike> in Postgres:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

And you only need to store `previous_address` (or more details), not <strike>`address`</strike>, nor <strike>`original_address`</strike>. Both would be redundant in a sane data model.

Comment: @ConsiderMe: Ties would not be possible with a `serial` column. But `created_at` is not a `serial`.

Comment: Postgres rocks! But I come upon this case (compound key component) too frequently and I work around it. And it's not just Postgres that can't do it. Begs the question, why even bother supporting compound keys?