# Autoincrement attribute based on another attribute

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I have a table `showtime` and a table `ticket`.

```
CREATE TABLE showtime (
    showtime_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    theatre_id      INT REFERENCES theatre(theatre_id),
    showroom_id     INT REFERENCES showroom(showroom_id),
    movie_id        INT REFERENCES movie(movie_id),
    start_time      TIME,
    end_time        TIME,
    show_date       DATE
);

CREATE TABLE ticket (
    showtime_id     INT REFERENCES showtime(showtime_id),
    seat_number     SERIAL UNIQUE,
    price           NUMERIC(1000, 2) NOT NULL,
    time_bought     TIME,
    date_bought     DATE,
    wasUsed         BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY     (showtime_id, seat_number)
);
```

As you can see, each row in `showtime` will have a unique `showtime_id`. What I want to happen is when a new `ticket` is added, the `seat_number` should auto-increment from the last value tied with `showtime_id`:

`ticket`

```
showtime_id     |   seat_number   |   instead_of   |
      1         |       1         |       1        |
      1         |       2         |       2        |
      1         |       3         |       3        |
      1         |       4         |       4        |
      2         |       1         |       5        |
      2         |       2         |       6        |
      3         |       1         |       7        |
      4         |       1         |       8        |
```

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Not without some soft of locking: every time you insert a ticket you lock a corresponding `showtime` row first and can do that safely. Otherwise you could do that in runtime using window functions, since that data is easily retrievable.

Answer (score 7):

Rephrasing your question, this is what you want: Whenever you `INSERT ticket` with a certain `showtime_id` you want to assign `seat_number` to the next higher number than already present in `ticket` for that `showtime_id`. So what is the highest `seat_number` already present? Simple:

```
SELECT max(seat_number)
FROM ticket
WHERE showtime_id = ?; -- The ? being a parameter placeholder in languages like Java
```

The `seat_number` data type should not be `serial` because you will have duplicate seat numbers for different `showtimes_id`s. Make it a simple `integer`.

In a single `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES
  (45,
   (SELECT max(seat_number) FROM ticket WHERE showtime_id = 45) + 1,
   ...
  );
```

To shield this logic from your users or application, you can use an insert trigger to avoid an erroneous or illegal (PK violation) seat number being entered:

```
CREATE FUNCTION assign_showtime_seat() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT max(seat_number) + 1 INTO NEW.seat_number
  FROM ticket
  WHERE showtime_id = NEW.showtime_id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_assign_showtime_seat
  BEFORE INSERT ON ticket
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE assign_showtime_seat();
```

There is a small chance that you encounter a concurrency problem where two tickets for the same `showtime_id` are entered almost simultaneously. The first insert enters the trigger and computes a new `seat_number`. Before the `INSERT` completes the second ticket insert enters the trigger and computes the same `seat_number`. Either one then manages the actual `INSERT` and completes, the second ticket entry then fails on insert with a duplicate `PRIMARY KEY` violation. The documentation provides [an example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) of recovering from such a concurrency problem.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible but either very unreliable for concurrent access or very expensive because you have to lock the whole table to be sure - locking rows will not be enough since you cannot lock rows that have not been entered, yet. (Well, with a separate `showtime` table, a row lock in the referenced table would help, but that only goes so far ... see comment by @zerkms)

If at all possible stick with the `serial` column you have now and use a `VIEW` or [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) to arrive at your numbers:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW v_ticket AS
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY showtime_id
                             ORDER BY seat_number) AS seat_number_effective
FROM   ticket;
```

This gives you ascending numbers without gaps per `showtime_id`.

Very similar:

- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)

Comment: I chose this answer because this handles the problem raised by zerkms.

Comment: "you cannot lock rows that have not been entered" --- but you only need to lock a `showtime` row which must exist already.

Comment: @zerkms: OK, that should work for INSERTing the next `seat_number`. But it will still be slow (potentially crippling slow) under heavy concurrent write load. And then you still don't have a solution for gaps introduced by DELETEs or UPDATEs. Numbers from a `SEQUENCE` are reliable and fast, and the VIEW produces a gap-less result.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter indeed (and I even mentioned that window functions is a better solution)