# PostgreSQL inner queries with prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, database-design, auto-increment

I have a table to store contacts.

I want to grab the max value of a column where adding user_id is {some number} and set that as the same column value for the current inserting record.

I'm using prepared statements:

```
pg_prepare($db, "add", 'INSERT INTO '.CONTACTS.' (c_user_serial,c_name,c_company,c_email)  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)');

$insert_co = pg_execute($db, "add", array({(MAX OF c_user_serial where c_user_id = 1234) + 1 increment },$name,$company,$email));
```

`c_user_id` is the ID of the user who is adding this contact, there is another column as index (`id`) that is a common `serial` column that increments for every row, `c_user_serial` is a serial number that increments per user. Let's say one user added one contact so it is `1`. After other users added many contacts, when this user adds his second contact I want this column to store `2`, so an auto increment kind of column but that should increment per user.

Not sure how to use inner queries here to get the max value of the column and use the incremented value for the current insertion.

Comment: I tried to write an answer, but then I noticed that this: `(MAX OF c_user_id where c_user_id = 1234)` doesn't make sense - If you know the c_user_id value is 1234, then the MAX is surely 1234. so there is no point to using the MAX function. Did something get mixed up in asking the question?

Comment: I tried to fix your question, but it's unclear what kind of number you want to retrieve, like Turophile commented. You also need to define what to do if the subquery would find NULL or no row.

Answer (score 1):

This query would do what you are asking for:

```sql
INSERT INTO contacts (c_user_serial, c_user_id, c_name, c_company, c_email)
SELECT max(c_user_serial) + 1, $1, $2, $3, $4
FROM   tbl
WHERE  c_user_id = $1;
```

Your original forgets to insert `user_id` itself, which is needed. I added it.

**However**, this carries a couple of principal problems:

1. The current "maximum" can be to subject of a ***race condition between concurrent transactions*** and is unreliable. (While a [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) is safe with concurrent access.)
2. If no row with `c_user = $1` is found, *nothing* is inserted. May or may not be what you want.
3. If  `max(c_user_serial)` returns NULL, another NULL value is inserted for `c_user_id`.
   If `c_user_id` is defined NOT NULL, that cannot happen.

To avoid problem 2. and 3. and start with `1` for every new user instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO contacts (c_user_serial, c_user_id, c_name, c_company, c_email)
VALUES (COALESCE((SELECT max(c_user_serial) + 1 FROM tbl WHERE c_user_id = $1), 1)
       , $1, $2, $3, $4)
```

"no row" is converted to NULL here and `COALESCE` defaults to `1` in this case.

#### Simple solution

Everything put together, the **simple solution** is:

```php
pg_prepare($db, "add"
     , 'INSERT INTO ' . CONTACTS . ' (c_user_serial, c_user_id, c_name, c_company, c_email)
        VALUES (COALESCE((SELECT max(c_user_serial) + 1 FROM tbl WHERE c_user_id = $1), 1)
               , $1, $2, $3, $4)');    
$insert_co = pg_execute($db, "add", array($user_id,$name,$company,$email));
```

Make sure that `CONTACTS` holds a properly escaped table name or you are wide open to **SQL injection**!

If you are looking for sequences *without gaps*, you must deal with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` *somehow*, which will inevitable honeycomb your sequences over time, which is one of the reasons, why **the whole idea is not that good**.

The other, more important reason is the race condition I mentioned. There is **no cheap and elegant solution** for it. (There are solutions, but more or less expensive ...)

If at all possible stick to *one* plain `serial` column for all rows. You can always attach numbers per user starting from 1 when retrieving data:

- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)

Comment: serial number is ok for all contacts, but I definetly need this partioned serial coulm too, because it doesnt look godd if we pass a different ID in the URL while deleting/updating and show a different number in the list (#You can always attach numbers per user starting from 1 when retrieving data:), so I need a column that really exists in DB, but Im not going to put that in my INSERT statement, but the DB engine should do an auto increment with user id partioning, seems it is possible with stored procedures, buit not very clear yet