# Problems with my attempt to implement an UPSERT

Tags: php, postgresql, if-statement, prepared-statement, upsert

I'm having this problem when checking a condition to update a table in PostgreSQL. It has to check if the user download this once and if yes, add +1 in `acessos`.

```
<?php
$result2 = pg_query("SELECT * from downloads WHERE (nome = $_POST[nome_download] AND email = $_POST[email_download])");
if (pg_num_rows($result2) == 0){
$result = pg_query("INSERT INTO downloads (nome, email, estado, arquivo, acessos) VALUES ('$_POST[nome_download]','$_POST[email_download]','$_POST[estado_download]','$_SESSION[nome_arquivo_download]','1')");
}else{
$arr[acessos] = $arr[acessos] + 1;
$result = pg_query("UPDATE downloads SET acessos = $arr[acessos] WHERE (nome = $_POST[nome_download] AND email = $_POST[email_download])");
}


if (!$result){
echo "Não foi possível realizar o cadastro. Tente fazer o download mais tarde.";
}
else
{
echo "soft_bd";
pg_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working. Else don't even execute and bugs me that I can't insert the same data in PostgreSQL in case the user downloads this more than one time.

Comment: You have a problem with SQL injection too. *Never* *ever* paste user input into SQL statement. Also, pg_num_rows can return -1

Comment: Have you verified that your Select statement returns the number of rows you expect?

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP, but I would remove the unnecessary `select`. Run the `update` as the first statement. If no row was updated, then run the insert. Or if only a few users download something more than once, then run the insert first, catch the unique key error and do the update. Which one is faster, depends on which happens more often: the update or the insert. If you can upgrade to Postgres 9.5 you can use `insert .. on conflict update` that does all that in a transactional safe way

Comment: I was using if (!$result2) and got the same problem. But I'll check this, @ChrisF. Thanks!

Comment: using this

$rows = pg_num_rows($result2);

echo $rows . " row(s) returned.\n";

I got nothing. No number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to `$arr` but it's not evident from your posted code where that is assigned. Either way, if you want to increase the current value of `acessos` by 1, this approach is **completely unsafe in a multi-user environment**.

You are also completely open to **SQL injection**. Use prepared statements instead.

In **Postgres 9.5** you can even do this in a ***single statement*** with the new [UPSERT implementation `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ON ... DO UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) - assuming there is a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `(nome, email)`:

```php
$sql = 'INSERT INTO downloads AS d (nome, email, estado, arquivo, acessos)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, 1)
        ON CONFLICT ON (nome, email) DO UPDATE 
        SET    acessos = EXCLUDED.acessos + 1';
```

For repeated calls, you might use [`pg_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) and [`pg_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php). For a single call use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php):

```php
pg_query_params($sql, array($_POST[nome_download]
                          , $_POST[email_download]
                          , $_POST[estado_download]
                          , $_SESSION[nome_arquivo_download]));
```

Comment: followed your tips and everything is working now. Thanks you all!