# Auto Increment a column with concatenated values in my SQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, auto-increment

I have this table with a column called wo_number, which is basically an auto-generated string value from a timestamp column. This kind of gives a unique value (since it take into account seconds and my application doesn't allow multiple inserts); the thing is, I want to scale for more than one insert in a second. Therefore, I want to make it 100% unique by auto-increment if two inserts came at the same time.

the wo_number column  value looks as follow:
WO-071821145515

I want it to look like this :
WO-071821145515 - 1  <<< where 1 is an auto-increment in case there is a duplication.

my table query is:

```
[create table work_orders (
id int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
time_stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
descreption text, 
requested_by varchar(100),
urgent BOOLEAN,
assigned_to varchar(100),
completion_date TIMESTAMP -- DEFAULT now(),
ack_date timestamp -- DEFAULT now(),
wo_number varchar(100) as (concat('WO-',replace(DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp,"%m%d%y%T"),':',''))),
remarks text, 
machine_id int,
department_id int,
employee_id int,
foreign key (machine_id) REFERENCES machines(id),
foreign key (department_id) REFERENCES departments(id),
foreign key (employee_id) REFERENCES employees(id)
);
```

[a simple select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1T60.png)

Comment: *I want to scale for more than one insert in a second.* Use SYSDATE() with according fractional part length.

Comment: See the following answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572959/5389997 then either follow that or use Akina's suggestion.