# How to prevent generating same UID when many users make registration at the same time in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, uniqueidentifier

I have registration form for users. They can registrate to the tour and I need to generate unique UID for each of their registration. I use `ID` as primary key and its autoincrement, but its only for system purpose only. I need to generate another `UID` which is used for pairing payments from bank account.

The format of UID I need to generate is `{TOUR_NUMBER}{REGISTRATION_NUMBER}`, so the numerical series can be like `59001, 59002, 59003` and so on (59 is number of the tour).

Currently I use this scenario.

```
1) count how many users registered to certain tour already
2) increment that number
3) with while() check if that incremented number is not already used
4a) if not, save the registration
4b) if it is, increment number again and continue with 3)
```

Problem is, that if there is many users at the same time, system generate the same UID for more users. I've tried to start `transaction` before point `1)` and commit them after `4a)` but it did not help.

--- EDIT ---

Maybe I did not explain my problem sufficiently. Let me try it again. Here are simplified tables I have. `Tour_id` and `registration_id` columns are auto-incremented.

| tour_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | England |
| 2 | Germany |

| registration_id | name | tour_id | payment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 1 | 1001 |
| 2 | John | 1 | 1002 |
| 3 | Jane | 1 | 1003 |
| 4 | Luke | 2 | 2001 |

`payment_id` is generated from `tour_id` and incremented number of total users registrated to the certain tour. The `payment_id` format can not be changed, it must be the way it is now, unfortunatelly. The value is used primarly for the payment pairing so it must be connected to certain user from the beginning and saved within user's tour registration.

I just need to ensure, that the `payment_id` will not be the same, which happend now from time to time, because delays in executing queries in my scenario above I guess. If it happends, the table looks like the table below, which I need to avoid - George and John have the same `payments_id` because they did registration at the same time. And `1002` is missing.

| registration_id | name | tour_id | payment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 1 | 1001 |
| 2 | John | 1 | 1001 |
| 3 | Jane | 1 | 1003 |
| 4 | Luke | 2 | 2001 |

Comment: You could just use a calculated column in the database to concatenate the tour number and the autoincrement ID. But why this specific format anyway? I'm assuming this isn't a bank account number. Why can't you just use the autoincrement on its own? Does this have to be sent to another application which only accepts a certain format, or something? It would be good to understand the constraints which led to this requirement.

Comment: @ADyson, Generated columns in MySQL cannot reference the auto-increment column. Try it.

Comment: @BillKarwin well it could be a calculation in a view or query then, I was using the term loosely I suppose, apologies.

Comment: As you can see, this question has been discussed on SO many times! I would take the hint from @ADyson (which is also echoed by Erwin's answer in the 2nd duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572959/5389997) and refrain from doing this. Generating the reference either in a query or a view is better than trying to create a new id field.

Comment: I edited my original post and add more informations to clarify my problem. I appreciate your answers, but I think there was missunderstanding about my problem (my bad I guess, I did not explain it good enought).