# sql increment value if exists otherwise insert with value 1

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Given following schema:

```
document(id, path);
term(id, description);
term_document(id_term,id_document,frequency);
```

Given a document `path` and term `description`, if I don't have a record of the `term` and the `document` in the table `term_documento` I want to insert into the table `term_document` with frequency = 1, otherwise, I want to just increment the `frequency` value.

What I came up so far is this:

```
insert into term_document(id_term, id_document, frequency)
select term.id, document.id, 1
from term, document where term.description='to' and document.path='/home/rogger/Projetos/projeto-ori-ufu/src/main/resources/d1.txt'
```

which satisties the case I dont have a record in term_document, but I don't know how to increment to satisfy both.

Comment: This is the reoccuring topic of sequences per id. If you have concurrent write access, the best answer is: don't. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24918964/939860

Comment: good point @ErwinBrandstetter, however is a very simple application and I wont have concurrent access to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique constraint on term_document(id_term, id_document), you can use `on conflict` clause in your insert:

```
insert into term_document(id_term, id_document, frequency)
select t.id, d.id, 1
from term t
cross join document d
where t.description = 'to'
    and d.path = '/home/rogger/Projetos/projeto-ori-ufu/src/main/resources/d1.txt'
on conflict (id_term, id_document) do update set frequency = frequency + 1;
```

I used cross join as you did (only in modern syntax). If there is actually a relation between the two table, you'd need to join them on those columns instead.

Comment: Note that INSERT...ON CONFLICT is only available in Postgres 9.5+.