# Select continuous groups by field, using the specified order

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need help solving the following tasks, where I need to use window functions. But I can not figure out how to get the id from a subquery sample to sort and apply aggregating functions:

Given table:

```
create temp table users(id bigserial, group_id bigint);
insert into users(group_id)
values (1), (1), (1), (2), (1), (3);
```

In this table, sorted by ID, you need:
to allocate continuous groups on group_id taking into account the

1. specified order of rows group (there are 4 of them)
2. count the number of records in each group
3. calculate the minimum record ID in the group

The result should be:

one of the columns is the group_id, another is the number of records, or the minimum id value, depending on the task. Rows should be sorted by id.

Output like this:

```
 group_id | count
----------+-------
        1 |     3
        2 |     1
        1 |     1
        3 |     1
```

Partial solution of the second task, without ordering:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), group_id
FROM ( SELECT id, id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER 
BY id) AS res, group_id FROM users)new_table
GROUP BY group_id,res;
```

That returns:

```
 group_id | count 
----------+-------
        1 |     3
        3 |     1
        1 |     1
        2 |     1
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that should be produced.

Comment: "taking into account the specified order of records (there are 4 of them)"? There are obviously more than 4 records, and *taking into account* does not define anything. Please describe your objective in a meaningful way. And you are not showing the desired *result* for the example, either.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT group_id
     , count(*) AS row_count  -- 2. count the number of records in each group
     , min(id)  AS min_id     -- 3. calculate the minimum record ID in the group
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , group_id
        , id - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY id) AS res
   FROM   users
   ) sub
GROUP  BY group_id, res
ORDER  BY min_id;  -- 1. specified order of rows group
```

Of course, if there can be gaps in the serial column `id`, you have to use:

```
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)
- row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY id) AS res
```

Typically, gaps in serial columns have to be expected.

Related answers with more explanation and links:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)
- [Grouping or Window](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397#166397)
- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)