# Can you create bigserial that is scoped to two other columns?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have an `object_id` column in an `objects` postgres table, but where each `object_id` is scoped to `org_id` and `type_id`. That is, each `object_id` is unique to each (`org_id`, `type_id`), so `object_id` is not unique in regards to the whole table but only in relation to those two properties.

Is that possible in postgres? If so, what do you need to do? If not, how should I handle "incrementing" this `object_id` in relation to the two scoping properties so that it is generally efficient during record creation? What is the standard approach? Note, there is no `id` on this table, the "id" is technically the tuple (`org_id`, `type_id`, and `object_id`), that triple-combo is what is "unique" globally.

I would like `object_id` to just be `bigserial`, but not sure that is possible.

Comment: "What is the standard approach?" -- Not to do it. Maybe [edit] the question and explain (in greater detail) what you are *actually* trying to model to get some suggestions on that. Could be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key