# UPDATE to assign serial numbers per group

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Table `users`:

| id | name | group_id | column to update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 1 |  |
| 2 | Mike | 1 |  |
| 3 | Charlie | 1 |  |
| 4 | Elza | 2 |  |

Table `groups`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | coolest group |
| 2 | random group |

Table `users` after update:

| id | name | group_id | column to update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Mike | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Charlie | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | Elza | 2 | 1 |

Group 1 has 3 users, we order them by name, and assign each an increment.
Group 2 has 1 user, we assign only one increment.

I'm trying to update users, per group, with increments on a specific column according to their name order.

So far I tried:

```
UPDATE users u
SET columntoupdate = g.increment
FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS increment
         FROM users u2 INNER JOIN groups g2 ON g2.id = u2.group_id
         WHERE u.group_id = g2.id
     ) g
```

But `u.group_id = g2.id` gives me an error about not being able to reference it in the subquery.

[Fiddle showing the problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b17608b6b71241c83266334edfaf52d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE users u
SET    columntoupdate = g.increment
FROM  (
   SELECT u2.id
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY u2.group_id ORDER BY u2.name) AS increment
   FROM   users u2
   ) g
WHERE u.id = g.id
-- AND u.columntoupdate IS DISTINCT FROM g.increment  -- ①
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e480c8f9871ac288bab690097503f9f7)*

No need to involve the table `group` at all.
You need to `PARTITION BY group_id` for serial number per group.
And join on the PK column.

① Add this `WHERE` clause to suppress empty updates (for repeated use). See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Aside:
You are aware that this data structure is not easily sustainable? Names change, users are added and deleted, gap-less numbers per group are expensive to maintain - and typically unnecessary. See:

- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer, what do you mean by empty updates ? affecting rows that already have a "serial number" and reupdating them with the same values ? concerning the data structure, I used an example so gaps are not a problem and names which aren't really names are immutables,

Comment: @adaba: Yes, updates that are not changing data (at full cost). Follow the link for details.